# html escape from z index div

Tags: html, css, z-index

i want to have navbar covering my video div, but when i want to do any content below video tag it just sticks to video container.

I want to change it to look like on image below:

[image]

```css
body, html {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web';
}
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navbar-toggler {
    padding: .25rem .75rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: .25rem;
    transition: box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.6s ease-out;
    z-index: 1;
}
main {
    color: #fff;
    clear: both;
}
.sticky {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
.navbar.scrolled {
    background: rgb(68, 68, 68); /* IE */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78); /* NON-IE */
}
  /* this is for ul tag */
  #myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    filter: brightness(25%);
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-transparent">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">

                        </ul>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
              <video playsinline autoplay muted loop poster="TheGuide.jpg" id="myVideo">
                <source src="https://ak8.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/8733538/preview/stock-footage-sydney-australia-january-social-media-internet-platform-networks-social-media-allows.webm" type="video/mp4">
              </video>
        </header>

        <main>
            <p>This is a simple HTML5 Template</p>
        </main>

        <footer>
            <p>HTML5 Template</p>
        </footer>
```

I was trying to use clear: both; on main tag but it still sticks above this video.

How can i just create content under my video element in html?